# Deleting Grid View Row data wrongly Windows Form My Code Attached?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gridview, delete-row

i am trying to delete grid view data as i am filling grid like,

```
  public void FillCompanyInfo()
    {
        DataTable dtCompanyInfo = new DataTable();
        dtCompanyInfo = objFunctions.GetCompanyInfo();
        if(dtCompanyInfo.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            dgvCompany.DataSource = dtCompanyInfo;
        }
        if (dtCompanyInfo.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (this.dgvCompany.Columns.Count == 8)
            {
                DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                checkColumn.Name = "";
                checkColumn.HeaderText = "Select";
                checkColumn.Width = 50;
                checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
                checkColumn.FillWeight = 10; //if the datagridview is resized (on form resize) the checkbox won't take up too much; value is relative to the other columns' fill values\\
                dgvCompany.Columns.Add(checkColumn);
            }
        }
    }
```

After filling grid i click on grid row and click delete button as,

```
  private void btn_Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvCompany.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells[8].Value))  //cells[4] CONTAINS CHECKBOX COLUMN
                {
                    string strId = r.Cells[1].Value.ToString();  //cells[0] CONTAINS EMPIDCOLUMN
                    objFunctions.DeleteCompany(strId);
                }
            }
            FillCompanyInfo();
        }
```

But it delete the data wrongly in my grid view i get fields numeric and string from 0 to 6 and chk box at 7th place while after binding data to grid i also attach one more column at 8 place may me it is due to some that reason ?

while debugging i suddenly notice at this place,

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvCompany.Rows)
```

that grid view have column in this manner chk box at zero position then seven fild and again then chk box at 8 place how it change the order ?

hopes for your suggestion thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the grid view data source before bind it.Please Refer this link to clear grid view. try this code

[Datagridview remove all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430933/datagridview-remove-all-columns)

public void FillCompanyInfo()
        {

```
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        dtCompanyInfo = GetCompanyInfo();
        if (dtCompanyInfo.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtCompanyInfo;
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            checkColumn.Name = "";
            checkColumn.HeaderText = "Select";
            checkColumn.Width = 50;
            checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
            checkColumn.FillWeight = 10; //if the datagridview is resized (on form resize) the checkbox won't take up too much; value is relative to the other columns' fill values\\
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkColumn);

        }

    }
```