# Windows Forms: Extra columns in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

My DataGridView is showing extra columns. The application is a windows forms application. What could I be doing wrong?

```
public ConvertisForm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Files| *.chm;*.htm;*.html;*.rtf;*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xps;*.doc;*.docx";    
    dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    dataGridView.ColumnCount = 5;

    dataGridView.RowCount = 20;
    //delete button
    var deleteDataGridViewButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
    {
        HeaderText = "",
        Name = deleteDataGridViewButtonColumnName,
        Text = "X",
        Width =20
    };
    dataGridView.Columns.Insert(DeleteColumnIndex, deleteDataGridViewButtonColumn);

    dataGridView.Columns[FileNameAndPathColumnIndex].Width=250;
    dataGridView.Columns[FileNameAndPathColumnIndex].HeaderText = "File Path";

    //browse button
    var browseDataGridViewButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
    {
        HeaderText = "",
        Name = browseDataGridViewButtonColumnName,
        Text = "...",
        Width = 30
    };
    dataGridView.Columns.Insert(BrowseButtonColumnIndex, browseDataGridViewButtonColumn);

    //convert to dropdown
    var convertToDataGridViewComboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    {
        HeaderText = "Convert to",
        Name = convertToDataGridViewComboBoxColumnName,
        DataSource = new ArrayList { convertToComboBoxDefault, "pdf", "word"},
        Width = 100,
        DefaultCellStyle =
        {
            NullValue = convertToComboBoxDefault,
            DataSourceNullValue = convertToComboBoxDefault
        }
    };

    dataGridView.Columns.Insert(ConvertToFileTypeColumnIndex, convertToDataGridViewComboBoxColumn);

    var convertDataGridViewButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
    {
        HeaderText = "",
        Name = convertDataGridViewButtonColumnName,
        Text = "Convert",
        Width = 50
    };
    dataGridView.Columns.Insert(ConvertButtonColumnIndex, convertDataGridViewButtonColumn);
    dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
    dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
    #endregion
}
```

[image]

Comment: is it this   dataGridView.ColumnCount = 5; ?

Comment: @active92 You don't have to make that a question.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

have you tried `DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;` ?

or you can **clear** all Columns before adding new Columns

see link for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7430993/5694113

Comment: his autogeneratedcolumns is already set to false but he put his columncount to 5. i think that's the reason why he is getting 5 columns.

Comment: God Bless @TheQuestioner. removing the ColumnCount=5, clearing the columns(before adding the columns) fixed the issue.

Comment: if you think a post helped you solve your question. please mark it as an answer. glad i helped :)